# Duplex printing does not work for letter-sized documents printed on A4 paper

Tags: printing, cups

I am trying to print on a network P-4026iw printer running CUPS 2.2.10, and I only have A4-sized paper.  When I try to print a letter-sized document, it prints one-sided.  In the sense that, if the printer is set to print two-sided, it does pull the paper back in after printing, and flips it upside down.  However, the second page comes out blank.

When set to print single-sided, it prints as expected.

This happens whether I'm printing from Safari, Acrobat reader, or lpr, but only for letter-sized documents; A4-sized documents print fine.  Also, running `lpr -o number-sides=2` on letter-sized documents works properly; on the other hand, setting two pages on a single sheet using other programs results in two pages being printed correctly on the front of the sheet; however, the back is empty again.

The output of my lpoptions command is:

```
job-cancel-after=10800
job-hold-until=no-hold
job-priority=50
job-sheets=none,none
marker-change-time=1579526659
marker-colors=#000000,none
marker-levels=20,-1
marker-names='PK-1012,Waste\ Toner\ Box'
marker-types=toner,waste-toner
number-up=1
printer-commands=AutoConfigure,Clean,PrintSelfTestPage
printer-info='Kopierer mit Duplex'
printer-is-accepting-jobs=true
printer-is-shared=false
printer-is-temporary=false
printer-location='Raum 115'
printer-make-and-model='P-4026iw MFP (KPDL)'
printer-state=3
printer-state-change-time=1579526659
printer-state-reasons=none
printer-type=10653780
printer-uri-supported=ipp://localhost/printers/Kopierer
```

Also, going to `http://localhost:631/printers/Kopierer` gives:

```
Defaults:   job-sheets=none, none media=iso_a4_210x297mm sides=two-sided-long-edge
```

Since I am not an administrator, I cannot change the default options; however, I can pass in command-line parameters.  How can I print my letter-sized documents on A4 paper to avoid the back page being blank?

Answer (score 0):

The paper needs to be rescaled before being sent to the printer.  One way to do this is:

```
pdftops -paper A4 filename.pdf - | lpr
```